# IPN simulator check always return INVALID

Tags: ruby, paypal, sinatra, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to help a friend (a Grails programmer) that has a problem testing the Paypal IPN listener with IPN simulator: he get always an INVALID response to the post.
So i wrote a Ruby version of the listener using Sinatra and http gem but i got stuck me too.

Here the very short piece of code for Sinatra server:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'http'

post '/' do
  request.body.rewind
  response = HTTP.post("https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr", body: "cmd=_notify-validate&#{request.body.read}")
  logger.info "response word: #{response.to_s}" # INVALID
  logger.info "response code: #{response.code}" # 200
end
```

I ran a tunnel to localhost (where Sinatra app is listening) using ngrok.
The app receive correctly the POST from the Paypal [IPN simulator](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/), add the required pair `cmd=_notify-validate`, return a POST. But the response is always "INVALID".

I tried to run the code on Heroku but in vain.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your `request.body.read` that you are adding to your request body is in the correct format, with no extra spaces or new lines?

Comment: yes, i'm sure. I was investigating if the problem is due to the coding format: is a problem if a space is converted to '%20' or a '+' ? ...